# SvnSystemException: Can't open file '...\format': Access Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn, sharpsvn

im using sharpSvn to get the last version in SVN repository, from own web application.

This is how i get last version: (C#)

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    client.CheckOut(new Uri("file://#URL#/"), "c:\\FOLDER");
 }
```

When is running on visual studio, works fine but when i trying to get last version from iis web app throw this exception:

"SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: Can't open file '\URL\format': Access denied."

What i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

The user account used by your webserver (probably something like 'IWAM_*') needs read rights on the #URL# directory for it to checkout from there.

For just checking out it doesn't need write rights to this directory.

Make sure the argument to new Uri() is in the following format

- `file:///C:/some/dir` for C:\some\dir
- `file://server/share/dir` for \server\share\dir
- `http://server/svn/repos` for a Subversion repository (E.g. [SvnEdge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion))

Before you can use a directory as a file:// style repository, you should create a repository using `svnadmin create`, or in SharpSvn the `SvnRepositoryClient.CreateRepository()`.